# Query relation in same table with Eloquent ORM in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am just discovering Laravel, and getting into Eloquent ORM. But I am stumbling on a little issue that is the following.

I have three tables with the following structures and data :

```
words

id | language_id | parent_id | word
-------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 0         | Welcome
-------------------------------------------
2  | 2           | 1         | Bienvenue
-------------------------------------------

documents

id | title
---------------------
1  | Hello World
---------------------

documents_words

document_id | word_id
--------------------------
1           | 1
--------------------------
```

As you see, we have a parent/child relationship in the words table.

The documents Model is defined as following

```
class Documents extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'documents';

public function words()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Word', 'documents_words', 'document_id');
}

}
```

And the words model :

```
class Word extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'words';

public function translation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Word', 'parent_id');
}


}
```

Now my problem is that I want to retrieve documents that have translated words, so I thought this would do it :

```
$documents = Documents::whereHas('words', function($q)
{
    $q->has('translation');
})
->get();
```

But I get 0 results, so I checked the query that Eloquent generates and uses :

```
 select * from `prefix_documents`
 where
 (
select count(*) from 
`prefix_words`

inner join `prefix_documents_words` 

on `prefix_words`.`id` = `prefix_documents_words`.`word_id` 

where `prefix_documents_words`.`document_id` = `prefix_documents`.`id` 

and (select count(*) 
from `prefix_words` 
where `prefix_words`.`parent_id` = `prefix_words`.`id`) >= 1

  ) >= 1
```

The problem is that it doesn't use aliases for the tables, what my query should be more like this to work (and it does) :

```
 select * from `prefix_documents`
 where
 (
select count(*) from 
`prefix_words`

inner join `prefix_documents_words` 

on `prefix_words`.`id` = `prefix_documents_words`.`word_id` 

where `prefix_documents_words`.`document_id` = `prefix_documents`.`id` 

and (select count(*) 
from `prefix_words` as `w`
where `w`.`parent_id` = `prefix_words`.`id`) >= 1

  ) >= 1
```

But how can I do this with Eloquent ORM ?

Thanks a lot for your help guys, hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Word Model, change the

```
public function translation()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Word', 'parent_id');
}
```

to

```
public function translation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Word', 'words', 'id', 'parent_id');
}
```

This way we are telling the Laravel to create an alias in the eloquent when using your query. I didn't test the other cases, but I think it will work.

Comment: Did you set up a table prefix in your database config file ? "prefix" is what I have set in my configuration.

Comment: If you put a "prefix" in the database configuration, the default behavior is that all your tables have to be an prefix before, like: prefixdocuments, prefixwords. So you have to change this in your eloquent model as well.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem right to me, I created the tables with migrations, and didn't have any problems with the Models until now, and I never mentioned the prefix anywhere else than in the database.php config file. Also I have set 'prefix_' in the config file, not just 'prefix'.

Comment: try removing the prefix. Is very weird that just the alias created have an prefix_. I make this in a fresh instalation of the laravel. I suggest that you do that too, just for garantee.

Comment: I also confirm that I have deleted my old tables, removed the prefix in the database.php config file, re-created my tables, and the generated query works fine ! So it really seems that it is an issue in the way that Eloquent ORM is generating the query string when a prefix is set.

Comment: I have accepted your answer since you solved my main issue, now there seems to be a problem with my tables and table prefix. Thanks !